# Restrict App Registration permissions in Azure

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to the restrict the permisson for an app registration in Azure?
For example, i grant an App the two Application Permissions:

- PermissionType: Application
- Permissions: Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All

The application runs in a "no-user-context" way, like a service user.
I now want to restrict the application that it can only read and write to one or more sharepoint sites (document libraries) but not to all sites in the tenant.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Is there another way, how this can be accomplished supporting oAuth 2.0 but no user acitivity is needed, because the app runs as a damon.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Microsoft only supports restricting access for apps using Exchange Online (mail/calendar/...) see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access).

But you can always use the [resource owner flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc). Then you can request a token as if you're a user. That user can be assigned specific access.

I'm not recommending this way, but if the regular client credentials are out of the question, it might be the way to go.

This flow is normally used by developers who want to migrate an old app with an native username/password field to use tokens, and don't want to go through all the OAuth2 hoops.